# How to Access method in Parent from Child Class

Tags: c#

I have one method which is in child class and I want to fetch that in Parent with the help of this.

```
public class Class1
{
    private class Class2
    {
        public void Add(int a, int b) // Method in Class 2
        {
            this.Add(a, b);
        }
    }

    public Class1() // constructor of Class 1
    { 
        // Get this Add method by This.Add ??
        // Not able to fetch the Add method here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Child and parent sound too much like inheritance.

Comment: It's not really clear (to me) what you mean by Fetch/Get. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would either have to create an instance of Class2 in the constructor of Class1 and use an instance method, or change the method Add to static in Class2

**Static version**

Something like

```
public class Class1
{
    private class Class2
    {
        public static void Add(int a, int b)
        {

        }
    }

    public Class1()
    {
        Class2.Add(1,2);
    }
}
```

**Instance version**

Something like

```
public class Class1
{
    private class Class2
    {
        public void Add(int a, int b)
        {

        }
    }

    public Class1()
    {
        new Class2().Add(1,2);
    }
}
```

Maybe have a look at [static (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx)

Comment: Actually I have a different concept. I want to use this.Class1 because there are some of the properties which I want to set in class1 based on Class2

Comment: Do you wish to call a method called Add, defined in Class1 in Add defined in Class2? Will you be using a static method? Can you pass an instance of Class1 to Class2?

Comment: @Moiz How would you do that? Since Class2 is private, how does an instance of Class2 exist before calling the constructor of Class1?

Comment: @Moiz You can't say `this.Class1`. And you can't say `this.Class2` because the nested class is a member of the _type_, not the individual object instance. You can make the inner class derive from the outer one, but not the other way.

Answer (score 2):

you have declared the method but it is in `class2`. that means you need to create an instance of `class2` in order to use the method

```
public class Class1
{
    private class Class2
    {
        public void Add(int a, int b) // Method in Class 2
        {
            this.Add(a, b);
        }
    }

    public Class1() // constructor of Class 1
    { 
        class2 cs = new class2();
        cs.Add(4,5);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Class1
{
    private class Class2
    {
        public void Add(int a, int b) // Method in Class 2
        {
            this.Add(a, b);
        }
    }

    public Class1() // constructor of Class 1
    {
        Class2 newclass2 = new Class2();
        newclass2.Add(1, 2);
        // Get this Add method by This.Add ??
        // Not able to fetch the Add method here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create instance for Class2

```
 public class Class1
 {
   private class Class2
    {
      public Class2() // constructor of Class2
      { 
      }

      public void Add(int a, int b) // Method in Class2
      {
        this.Add(a, b);
      }
    }

public Class1() // constructor of Class1
{ 
    Class2 cs2 = new Class2();
    cs2.Add(4,5);
}
```

}